# Как в Woo сделать панель в админке, которая показывает купленные услуги с фильтром по клиентом?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Ребята помогите, есть e-магазин по продаже услуг. (WP + Woo). Как сделать некую панель в админке, которая отражала бы купленные услуги, с фильтром по клиентом? Чтобы можно было админу сделать выборку по клиенту и понять какие он уже купил услуги. В идеале еще возможноcть их редактировать (например, отменять/добавлять это право у них или подобные операции).
Возможно есть уже готовый плагин, это было бы отличное решение.